# UpdatePanel in ascx

Tags: c#, ajax, updatepanel

Hei, I have an ajax UPdatepanel in master page who male reference to usercontrol, I make another updatepanel inside this usecontrol but i dont get the event.
I'm new in Ajax and i tried but i dont get it, can anybody help me.
Thanks

```
Master.cs
UpdatePanel - reference to search.ascx Parententer 
UpdatePanel - reference to Form.ascx Child

Master.cs

    protected void SokBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Db.Freetext = txtBuscador.Text.Trim();
            Db.itemId = 0;
            MainContent.Controls.Clear();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBuscador.Text))
            {
                search Search = (search)LoadControl("~/search.ascx");
                Search.FreeText = txtBuscador.Text;
                Search.UserId = idUser;
                MainContent.Controls.Clear();
                MainContent.Controls.Add(Search);

            }
        }


        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnSearch" eventname="Click" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                              
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

    Search.ascx

    <div id="divContenidoGestion" style="width:1060px; top:250px; position:absolute;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="always"  >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Item" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```